# Is it possible to automatically access videos from iOS gallery in my app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to post-process videos from the iOS gallery to present user with some information about their captured video.

Using `UIImagePickerController`, it's possible to present user with a File picker interface where the user can individually select a file for processing within an external app.

**In contrast to that, is it possible to "automatically" access videos from the iOS gallery "without" a manual selection by the user?** I intend to process video files from the gallery one-by-on, and present user with the data for all videos in his gallery.

I need the relevant APIs, which I have been unable to find it yet.

It's perfectly fine if I need to copy the video within my app documents directory before I can process it.

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS 10, we also need to provide photo library usage description in info.plist file. The application user will get a prompt that he/she wants the application to access his/her gallery content. If no then you cannot get the gallery images/videos.

Answer (score -1):

[Asset programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/)

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    if let referenceURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? NSURL {
        let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs([referenceURL], options: nil)
        if let phAsset = fetchResult.firstObject as? PHAsset {
            PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestAVAssetForVideo(phAsset, options: PHVideoRequestOptions(), resultHandler: { (asset, audioMix, info) -> Void in
                if let asset = asset as? AVURLAsset {
                    let videoData = NSData(contentsOfURL: asset.URL)

                    // optionally, write the video to the temp directory
                    let videoPath = NSTemporaryDirectory() + "tmpMovie.MOV"
                    let videoURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: videoPath)
                    let writeResult = videoData?.writeToURL(videoURL, atomically: true)

                    if let writeResult = writeResult where writeResult {
                        print("success")
                    }
                    else {
                        print("failure")
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My question specifically mentions that I do not want to use the "ImagePicker" interface. I'm giving your reply a "-1", so that I can expect a better answer. Thanks anyways..